# MySQL deadlocks when there shouldn't be

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I have a queue in a MySQL InnoDB table and 10 daemon processes that process this queue.
The table "queue" has:

- id (auto-increment primary key)
- daemon (integer to record which daemon is working that item)
- processed (tinyint to show that processing is complete)
- other fields as needed

My simplistic approach is to, for each deamon, reserve x rows in the queue table, and then process them.

To reserve rows, I have:

`UPDATE queue SET daemon={daemonId} WHERE daemon IS NULL LIMIT {x}`

eg:
`UPDATE queue SET daemon=3 WHERE daemon IS NULL LIMIT 50`

I get a lot of MySQL deadlocks here due to concurrency, but that should not be a problem. If a daemon fails to reserve rows, it will just continue with nothing, and try again in the next loop iteration.

Once reserved, I read in the rows:

`SELECT * FROM queue WHERE daemon={daemonId} AND processed=0`

eg:
`SELECT * FROM queue WHERE daemon=3 AND processed=0`

And then I process each item.

After processing an item, I mark it as completed:
`UPDATE queue SET processed=1 WHERE id={id}`

eg:
`UPDATE queue SET processed=1 WHERE id=657954`

The thing I can't understand is that I'm getting MySQL errors in the log, eg:

`Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction UPDATE queue SET processed='1' WHERE id='69215794'`

How can this be?

Since each deamon reserves it's rows, I don't see any way for different deamons to compete for the same rows, and I see no way that an individual daemon can deadlock itself.

Comment: `show engine innodb status` will give you more details. Why you get the deadlock exactly depends on more details than you gave here, but just as an example: session 1 marks first 50 rows as his own, session 2 marks the next 50 (but was required to read the first 50 rows and skip them because they were not null). If your first query now would change row 2 to `daemon = null` (it doesn't, but it could, it's just a row-lock, it forgot why it was locked), it would change the result of the first query of session 2 (it would have to take row 2 then). If you get a deadlock from that depends on ...

Comment: ... things like where you start/end your transactions or the isolation level, so I'm not sure if it's that. If you don't do it already, you could try to start and end a transaction just around your first query (the marking with `limit`) and then start a new one for the rest of your code (though as I said, it depends on your actual code). Some general tipps against deadlocks: [How to Minimize and Handle Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html).

Comment: I've done a show engine innodb status and the results of the deadlock are here: http://pastebin.com/yMJPw18N

Unfortunately I don't really understand it.

The locks seem to always be between a daemon reserving rows, and a daemon marking a row as complete.

What I don't get is that these rows do NOT intersect. The criteria for selecting rows to reserve will never be the same as updating a previously reserved row. So why are they competing for locks?

Comment: Are you explicitly locking tables before your select?

Comment: I'm not explicitly locking anything. And autocommit is on.

Comment: one more clarification before I have a crack at this, how many rows does `SELECT * FROM queue WHERE daemon=3 AND processed=0` read in at once

Comment: Each daemon tries to get reserve up to 50 rows with UPDATE queue SET daemon=3 WHERE daemon IS NULL LIMIT 50. When reading again, the daemon gets all it's reserved items with SELECT * FROM queue WHERE daemon=3 AND processed=0. In theory this would only be up to 50 items each time.

Comment: Did you sort this out? I didn't get a notification for your last comment so only just saw it two weeks later. (Hint use @username when you want to send someone a notification about a comment)

Comment: I got this sorted out enough. Oddly the described behaviour happens with PHP's mysql extension, but not with the mysqli extension. When I converted things to work with mysqli (since mysql will be removed soon), everything started working fine. No other changes were made except moving to mysqli. Weird or what?